# What are the compelling reasons to use a MemoryCache over a plain old Dictionary<string,object>

Tags: c#, .net, caching

I have just come across the [MemoryCache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.memorycache.aspx) which is new in .NET 4.

I get that it can be useful if you want to:

- Limit the total memory usage of the cache
- Have an object expiry time (time to live) for objects you put in the cache

Are there any other compelling reasons to use a MemoryCache over a standard `Dictionary<string,object>`

I have a few books on C# and .NET and there is no reference to it anywhere.

Comment: I am confused. How would a `Dictionary<string,object>` be persisted in memory?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

I think you nailed the two compelling reasons :-)

The MemoryCache has an eviction strategy, so that it can throw out entries that are no longer needed or for that you do not have enough memory anymore.

A Dictionary will not "lose contents".

**Update:** MemoryCache is thread-safe and has methods such as AddOrGetExisting. With a Dictionary, you'd have to synchronize access yourself (or use ConcurrentDictionary).

Comment: Yeah this eviction idea looks interesting - I see that by setting the [CacheItemPolicy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.cacheitempolicy.aspx) on an item you can add a SlidingExpiration (evicted if it has not been accessed in a given span of time) or you could add some other custom conditions as well, such as a file on disk being modified.

Comment: The one feature which I miss in MemoryCache is save/load from file.