# Caching multiple XML files in c#

Tags: c#, xml

I have around 4000 xml files in a folder. I need to loop all of them and insert them into Cache so that when the Cache has these files program will retrieve from there.
I tried using AggregateCacheDependency however I am not sure what do I pass in Cache. Insert’s value parameter. My question is how do I get all the Xml files in Xmldocument.load and pass this as a value to Cache.Insert method ?
How to retrieve it from Cache?

Any help would be highly appreciated...

Comment: This feels like a XY Problem - https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem . **Why** do you need to cache them? Towards what end?

Comment: We require a warm up script sort of thing..This program wil be used in task scheduler at the time of server restart. So that when cache has files , it wil be retrieved from the cache itself to enhance performance.

Comment: Have you identified that the performance issue is real? What makes you think a cache will help?

Comment: Can you let me know if this is possible in .net c#?

Comment: Yes it is possible. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.caching.memorycache?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: I had gone through this post. It only refers to one single text file whereas I need to refer many XML files.

Comment: Yeah I have tried it and it works. However this wont work for many XML files. And if cache has files in it , I wil have to retrieve them from the cache as well

Comment: Why won't it work for many XML files?

Comment: The fastest method is to put data into a dictionary (Dictionary<string, XDocument>).  No need for a hash.  The key is the name of the file.

Comment: @jdweng I am not sure what you mean by `no need for a hash` - `Dictionary` definitely uses hashes. _I'd also be cautious about using `Dictionary` given thread-safety - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7251535/what-are-the-compelling-reasons-to-use-a-memorycache-over-a-plain-old-dictionary ._

Comment: I actually did something like that and used regular file system caching with name conventions. I created for 40 different affiliates, 10 reports each, over 10 different time durations each. So all in all I had 4000 xmls. I would call one of them typically "Aff_234_report_22_time_oneWeek.xml" or something like that. They would run over the night process, and the next day would be snarfed for usage.

Comment: Can anyone send me a working code . I am having a hard time figuring it out...

Comment: I know a dictionary uses hash.  OP want to use hash and not a dictionary.

Comment: `OP want to use hash and not a dictionary.` Where does it say that they want to use a hash @jdweng?

Comment: "I need to loop all of them and insert them into Cache"

Comment: @jdweng Ah - I think you said `hash` a number of times and meant `cache`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks a lot for ur help. Your solution worked. I iterated over the XDocument and gathered its values into list of xdocument which was passed to cache.